# remove item from a list by specific index

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this table:

```
local ls = {
   ["foo"] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   ["bar"] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
}
```

I want to remove "foo" from list.

I tried this:

```
table.remove(ls, "foo")
```

but returns a error: "Only numbers"

Okay, but I can't input a number. This list isn't static, in my code a lot of indexes will be inserted in this list.

The question is, is there other way to do this or other function that fit my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.remove` only works for a sequence. In your code, the table `ls` isn't one.

To remove an entry from a table, just assign the value of specific key to `nil`:

```
ls.foo = nil
```